# reparametrizing Lie group with diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I am concerned by the statement that "we can reparametrize our group elements by using the diagonalized matrix," in the case below.

Group: SO$(1,1)$ = $2\times 2$ matrices with determinant = 1 satisfying $O^T=gO^{-1}g^{-1}$ with 
$g=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}$.

I determined that matrices in this group look like $\begin{pmatrix} 
a & b \\ 
b & a 
\end{pmatrix}$.

On the way to parametrizing this to make an isomorphism to $(\mathbb{R},+)$ more clear, we diagonalized this general form matrix, where the eigenvalues are $a-b, a+b$, and using the condition that the detminant = 1, we got
$\begin{pmatrix} 
a-b & 0 \\ 
0 & \frac{1}{a-b} 
\end{pmatrix}$

Question: How is this matrix still an element of the group?! Diagonalization is not equivalence is it? It's technically Original matrix = $P^{-1}D P$ where P are the eigenvector matrices and D is the eigenvalue diagonal matrix. Who says that if the original matrices forms a group, the D matrices form a group?!

Answer (score 1):

Given an original matrix $M,$ we have (as you already said)
that $M = P^{-1}DP.$

Therefore we also have that $D = PMP^{-1}.$

Given two diagonal matrices $D_1,$ $D_2$ from the diagonalized set,
$$D_1D_2 = PM_1P^{-1}PM_2P^{-1} = P(M_1M_2)P^{-1}$$
where $M_1$ and $M_2$ are the "original" matrices of $D_1$ and $D_2$,
so $M_1M_2$ is a member of the original group, so $D_1D_2$ is a member of the diagonalized set. So there's the closure property.

If $M$ is in the "original" group then so is $M^{-1}$.
Then $D = PMP^{-1}$ and $E = PMM^{-1}P^{-1}$ are members of the diagonalized set,
$$ DE = PMP^{-1}PMM^{-1}P^{-1} = I, $$
similarly we find $ED = I,$ so $E = D^{-1}$. There's the property of inverses.

I'll leave the identity and associativity for you to work out.

Comment: Ah brilliant, so these matrices form a group! But there is no guarantee they are the same group right? We can however say they're isomorphic?

Comment: In general I think yes, they would be a different group, although isomorphic to the original group.